# Azure deployment slots and login with AD

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have WebApp in Azure with authentication in Azure AD.

The flow: Click login -> redirect to something like this: "login.microsoft..." -> redirect to page configured in AD.

And now I have slot for this app.

It use this same AD app and redirect to main page not to slot.

Can be configured to redirect to slot but with that same AD app?

@Edit:
When I trying add link to slot in Azure AD:

```
https://myapp.myname-ase-01.p.azurewebsites.net
https://myapp-staging.myname-ase-01.p.azurewebsites.net
```

It says that the second Url is different root than other and do not update settings... What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

not unless you use different Azure AD Applications for different slots. or maybe you redirect to an intermediate location and that location redirects to proper place depending on the request that you send to Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple redirect URIs on the app. You can add one for your slot there.

Then you will need to pass the `redirect_uri` parameter when redirecting to login. How this is done exactly depends on your framework.

Comment: In AD settings I can add only one "Reply URL". I use ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: If you find your app under Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations in Azure portal, you should be able to add more. Are you using the Easy Auth offered by Azure Web Apps or is it configured in your app?

Comment: Its configured in Azure AD.